# Why are some websites seemingly immune to self-signed certificate MitM attacks?

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, man-in-the-middle

I recently did an experiment using MitM to gain account information (username and password) while accessing websites. I used two PCs in the scenario; one as the target, running Internet Explorer, and one as the attacker, running ettercap. One attempt (pretending to be steamcommunity.com) yielded information; the target accepted the attacker's fake CA self-signed certificate presented via the MitM attack. The other attempt (pretending to be facebook.com) didn't even allow me to add an exception for the self-signed certificate on the target machine. So the question is, why did one website allow me to add an exception while the other one didn't?

Comment: If I were to make a guess it would be because the SteamCommunity.com certificate isn't an EV certificate.  But I will let you do the research on that.

Comment: My first thought was HTTP Public Key Pinning (HPKP), but it doesn't seem like Internet Explorer supports that. HPKP is an attempt to prevent browsers from being fooled by phony certificates presented by MitM attackers, even if the cert was issued from a CA the browser already trusts.

Comment: The certificate of *steamcommunity.com* isa  perfectly valid EV certificate, I just tested it, https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=steamcommunity.com&latest From this page there seems to be no weakness, better than facebook's site, actually. **Plot thickens**. But are you sure you would not be better served by posting this question on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions ?

Comment: thanks for the answers and the correction, i will try asking the same question on crypto.stackexchange.com/questions.

Answer (score 0):

After the [DigiNotar incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar#Issuance_of_fraudulent_certificates) the large browser vendors started to *pin* the certificates or public keys of certain "high profile" sites (which facebook definitely is), in order to prevent the usage of fraudulent certificates. I am not aware of a statement from Microsoft, if IE does that, too, but the have a similar concept called [Certifiacte Reputation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2014/03/10/certificate-reputation-a-novel-approach-for-protecting-users-from-fraudulent-certificates/)